# Where do I find detailed instructions on installing the community version of Openshift?

Tags: openshift

Most of the instructions online are either for the full/trial version of Openshift.
I was looking for recent instructions and downloads that would allow me to install the Openshift community version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenShift is the Red Hat supported product, the upstream Open Source version is **OKD**.

The OKD home page is https://github.com/openshift/okd and their public documentation is currently on https://docs.okd.io/latest/welcome/

Several different installation options are documented there.